# What is the time complexity of multiplying a column vector by a row vector?

Tags: matlab, time-complexity, linear-algebra

I am programming in MATLAB. I think that (case A) a column vector of length N multiplied by a row vector of length D has a computational complexity of O(ND), and (case B) a matrix of NxD multiplied by a row vector of length D also has a computational complexity of O(ND). Why did I write the program, and after running it, the computation time for (case A) is much larger than (case B)? Here are my MATLAB code. Please run this program in MATLAB. You will find a huge difference between t1 and t2. t1 is surprisingly 10 times longer than t2. Why is this? Can anyone give me an answer? Does anyone know how to modify this program so that the computation time for Case A is reduced to Case B?

```
N=1e4;D=200;
xx=rand(N,D);

onesN=ones(N,1);
onesD=ones(D,1);
tic

% Case A
for i=1:N
    xxi=xx(i,:);
    kk=onesN*xxi;% o(N*D)
end

t1=toc
tic

% Case B
for i=1:N
    mm=xx*onesD;% o(N*D)
end

t2=toc
```

I tried the above code. The computation time of Case A is 10 times more than Case B with the same time complexity. How can I shorten the computation time of Case A?

Comment: O() notation doesn’t say anything about the cost of an operation, it only tells you how the cost scales as the input grows. Case A produces an NxD matrix, whereas case B produces a length N vector. The latter is much cheaper. There are many issues with this code. For one, the indexing `xx(i,:)` is relatively expensive, and you don’t use it in case B. Two, in case B you compute N times the same thing. Three, `tic`/`toc` is not precise enough to measure very quick computation like this, use `timeit` instead.